# Creation of specific table for Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle

I have to make a table with some specifications and restrictions. I'm not very familiar with automatic table creation. I have to make this for Oracle DB.
Table name: A0

```
Primary key (NUMBER), A0_PK
Date (DATE), A0_DATE
VARCHAR2, A0_INTERVAL
Value (NUMBER), A0_VALUE
Other 1000 columns, called for example. A0_COL_058
```

Table should be filled 100.000 rows, random values, with constraint:

```
Primary key is sequential: 1, 2, 3...
Date: only days (without time) for year 2013.
A0_INTERVAL, like date but string in YYYYMMDD format
Value: number in [0, 100]
Others: null
```

I have to make an script? What is the extension of script file and where it is executed?
Can someone please point me in the right direction, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: It is a bad idea to implement dates as strings, it's better to store them as `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` and converse them to appropriate format as needed with `to_char` function. The extension doesn't matter, and the scripts are usually run with SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the basic setup i'd suggest something along the following lines:

```
    CREATE TABLE A0 (
          a0_pk         NUMBER
        , a0_date       DATE
        , a0_interval   VARCHAR2(20)
        , a0_value      NUMBER
        , CONSTRAINT c_a0_pk        PRIMARY KEY (a0_pk)
        , CONSTRAINT c_a0_date      CHECK ( a0_date >= TO_DATE ( '01.01.2013 00:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) AND a0_date < TO_DATE ( '01.01.2014 00:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) )
        , CONSTRAINT c_a0_value     CHECK ( a0_value BETWEEN 0 AND 100 )
    );


    BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
            INSERT
              INTO A0
                 ( a0_pk
                 , a0_date
                 , a0_value
                 )
            VALUES
                 ( i
                 , TO_DATE ( '01.01.2013 00:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) + 365 * DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
                 , TO_CHAR ( a0_date, 'YYYYMMDD' )
                 , FLOOR ( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE ( 0, 101 ) )
                 )
                 ;
        END LOOP;
    END;

    UPDATE A0
       SET a0_interval = TO_CHAR ( a0_date, 'YYYYMMDD' )
         ;

    COMMIT;

    ALTER TABLE A0 ADD CONSTRAINT c_a0_interval  CHECK ( TO_CHAR ( a0_date, 'YYYYMMDD' ) = a0_interval );
```

note that you may omit the `CONSTRAINT` lines apart from the pk constraint in the table creation statement if you do not need the constraints to be enforced by the dbms.
after the creation of the table, all remaining columns can be created by statements like

```
ALTER TABLE A0 ADD ( A0_COL_001 NUMBER );
```

given the number of 1000 columns, the list of statements is best generated by some short perl script. alternatively, fill 3 columns in a spreadsheet. column 1 shall hold 1000 instances of the string `a`, column 3 `b`, respectively. fill column2 with numbers from 0 to 999 and format them to 3 digits with leading zeroes. save the result as a csv file. edit that file by replacing `a;` with `ALTER TABLE A0 ADD ( A0_COL_` and `;b` with `NUMBER );`, respectively, assuming that you chose `;` to be the csv separator.